# mysql asterisk country code prefixes query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with prefixes. Before the call routing I want to have mysql query that checks presence of prefix in db.

For example US prefix is 1 and Trinidad and Tobago is 1 868. But US prefix can be in that table and T&T prefix - no. If it is absent I want the call to be terminated.

```
1  | US
38 | Ukraine

And for example I dial 18681111111 to T&T
```

Comment: How your table looks like?

Comment: If your `prefixes` table look like columns: `'id', 'name'`, values: `[1, 'US'], [1868, 'T&T'],...` then you can simple use `SELECT * FROM prefixes WHERE id = 1;` OR `... WHERE id = 1868`. Maybe you create a bad table to store it's data? Give us your table structure.

Comment: Do you have a mean to *identify* (without doubt) the prefix part in the phone number?

Comment: no( cause numbers in different countries have different length

Comment: You should probably split the US record into multiple records that would define only the valid prefixes. For example, 10 through 17 and 19, and maybe 18smth but not include T&T... i'm afraind there is not much else you can do without knowing the phone structure of your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from countrycodestbl where '92111111111' like concat(countrycode,'%') limit 1;
```

The table "countrycodestbl" should have all valid countrycodes

When you run the above query you will get the "92"